# Memory consumption by a client process on oracle DB server

Tags: oracle, memory, process

We have a database (12c) running on exadata server. Application connects to the database using JDBC and MQL from a remote client machine (Different from DB server). There are almost 5000 application connections to the database. Our DB configuration is as below.

SGA : 40 GB
PGA : 10 GB
process parameter : 10000

I would like to understand whether the processes (count: 5000) which are coming from client machine consume any memory on the DB server? I know each process will consume some amount of memory in PGA. But i would like to understand if any memory is consumed on the DB server, other than the allocated PGA.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that Oracle sessions memory would be handled within the Oracle memory and not pull separate memory from the operating system. The Oracle Real-World Performance folks have stated (as a common computer science axiom) that a machine can handle up to 100 simultaneous connections per CPU core.  It sounds like you may be getting a Logon Storm**:

> **Logon Storm: 
>   A logon storm is characterized by a sudden spike in the number of client connection requests or an unusually high number of
>   connections.  Since the process of starting a database session is CPU
>   intensive, a logon storm will likely result in unexpected consequences
>   such as: connection errors, applications waiting on CPU, timeouts,
>   poor response time, impacts to other DB’s on same machine, elevating
>   wait times for everything running on the instance, … .   The root
>   causes of the logon storms are often traced back to improper
>   connection pool settings or applications connecting, using a session,
>   then disconnecting.